# Why use looper in thread

Tags: android

I found these part of code, that uses a service to register LocationListener (lm), that will listen for location changes.

In onStart a new thread is created, because in the other way the service would run in the main thread.

But I don't understand why do I need to use a looper in this thread? Also, do I need to stop it somehow somewhere?

And until when does this thread run? I know that usually, a thread finishes when its run method is finished, but what happens in this case? I guess that it needs to be running all the time, so that location listener could listen for changes?

```
onStart(Intent intent, intstartId) 
{ 
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    triggerService = new Thread(new Runnable() 
    { 
        public void run() 
        {
            try
            {
                Looper.prepare(); 
                lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                myLocationListener= new GPSListener(); long minTime= 10000; 
                float minDistance= 50; 
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTime, minDistance, myLocationListener);
                Looper.loop();
            }
            catch(Exception e) 
            { 
                Log.e("MYGPS", e.getMessage() ); 
            } 
       }
 }); 
triggerService.start(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I don't understand why do I need to use a looper in this thread? Also, do I need to stop it somehow somewhere?

Since you'r listener will be activated or listen the event on each `long minTime= 10000;`

if this time elapsed and on `float minDistance= 50;` and on minDistance the object is moved

and when this occurs the listener do his job and update the location.

> lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTime, minDistance, myLocationListener);

after this it has to go back and set the current location and again wait for the event to occur.

> do I need to stop it somehow somewhere?

You don't need to stop it.

And until when does this thread run?

This thread will be executed until you terminate or exit the location service.

> a thread finishes when its run method is finished, but what happens in this case? I guess that it needs to be running all the time, so that location listener could listen for changes?

Yes this thread will be executed all the time, or you stop it manually by terminating the service.

Usually we use these types of thread to increase the responsiveness of the program so the main program can perform some other task instead of waiting for the location service.

Comment: Thank you for you detailed answer. Something confuses me, what would happen if I remove Looper.loop() and Looper.prepare()? The thread would finish and I would not be able to listen for location changes? So, you are saying that the thread will be running till I call stopSelf or stopService, is that correct?

Comment: if you remove the loop the thread will be terminated, I am telling for this situation if you use looper then it will not terminate. If you remove the looper.loop() then the thread will be exited after completing his job.

Comment: Just one more question, if the thread without loop() finishes, in which thread will the service continue to run? And will its listener respond to changes?

Comment: the service continues to run in parent thread or main thread And the listener will not respond since the listener is not running, you are making you'r listner to listen in the child thread.

Answer (score 0):

Loopr.prepare() assigns a message loop to a thread. once you have a message loop you can
push requests into it (to be activated by the assigned thread) using 
handler.post().

But...

Why on earth would you want to use a worker thread, with or without a msg loop
in order to request location updates?

The Android location notification API is an asynchronous API which was designed to
be activated via the the UI thread. Many aspects of correct Android 
development will require you to spawn threads. Not this one.

And as a side note, your code tells me that you are looking for a 50m location granularity.

If that is the case, please consider using the new [fused location provider](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.htmhttps://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html).

Using the fused provider with priority set to [PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html) will
give you an SLA of 40 meter error range with battery consumption of ~ 0.6% per hour. Way
cheaper than using GPS..

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was told that it is better to listen for this events in a service, so that the main thread is not occupied by being notified all the time. Something like @ali786 said - Usually we use these types of thread to increase the responsiveness of the program so the main program can perform some other task instead of waiting for the location service. I'm just an android beginner, so I can't tell what is a good approach. What I want to do is to get user location on button click,but I was told that I should listen for it all the time, so I wouldn't have to wait location fix?